# Using getopts to parse options after a non-option argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I have a bash script as below in a file `nepleaks_upd.sh`, that I want to run as `./nepleaks_upd.sh bootstrap --branch off`. Couldn't make it to take `--branch` , but what it works with is `./nepleaks_upd.sh bootstrap -b off`.

```
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [prepare | up | down]  [-b <on/off>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }                                                                                                 

case "$1" in                                                                                           
               bootstrap)                                                                                  
                  while getopts ":b:" o; do                                                            
                   case "${o}" in                                                                      
                    b)                                                                                 
                        b=${OPTARG}                                                                    
                        if [ ${b} == "off" ]; then                                                      
                               echo "git clone https://github.com/iPrayag/dotfiles.git"  
                               ## logic                                                      
                        fi                                                                             
                        ;;                                                                             
                    *)                                                                                 
                        echo ${o}                                                                      
                        usage                                                                          
                        ;;                                                                             
                   esac                                                                                
                  done                                                                                 
                  shift $((OPTIND-1))                                                                  
                  echo "option1 = ${o}" 
                  echo "option2 = ${b}"                                                                      
                  if [ -z "${b}" ]; then                                                               
                         usage                                                                         
                  fi                                                                                   

                    ;;                                                                                 
                up)                                                                                         
                     echo "up"     
                     ##logic                                                                    
                     ;;                                                                                
                down)                                                                                  
                     echo "down" 
                     ##logic                                                                     
                    ;;                                                                                 
                *)                                                                                     
                    echo "Usage: $0 {up | down} dev"                                                
                    exit 1                                                                             
                    ;;                                                                                 
esac
```

Without first `case  .. in .... esac`, it works fine. With `case ... in ... esac`, it gives blank option for `-b`,

```
$ ./nepleaks_upd.sh bootstrap -b off
option1 = ?
option2 = 
Usage: ./nepleaks_upd.sh [bootstrap | up | down]  [-b <on/off>]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check for options before you use `$1`?

Comment: @unxnut It sings samething bro

Comment: What do you mean by “Without first `case .. in .... esac`, it works fine”? Do you mean that lines 5-25 parse `./nepleaks_upd.sh -b off` correctly? Maybe you need a `shift`, so `getopts` doesn’t choke on the “`bootstrap`”.

Comment: @Scott Yes, exactly that part works fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`getopts` starts parsing at the first argument and stops at the first non-option arguments. That's the standard convention — some GNU utilities accept options after arguments, but the normal thing is that in `somecommand foo -bar qux`, `-bar` is not parsed as an option.

If you want to start parsing options after `bootstrap`, you need to indicate that. `getopts` uses the `OPTIND` variable to remember what position it's at. `OPTIND` starts out with the value 1. To skip the first argument, set it to 2.

```
case "$1" in
   bootstrap)
      OPTIND=2
      while getopts ":b:" o; do
          …
```

Alternatively, you could `shift` the arguments that you've already processed.

```
subcommand=$1; shift
case "$subcommand" in
    bootstrap)
      while getopts ":b:" o; do
          …
```