# bash --- parse flags and an expected (non-optional) argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments, getopts

```
$ bash file.sh expected_arg -f optional_arg
```

I've seen posts that address using `$1` to grab the first argument

and posts that address using getopts for parsing flag arguments. I haven't seen a post that addresses both.

I'm currently accessing `expected_arg` via `$1`.

I can't process the `-f` flag at all. Even though I also have this in my test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname=$1

[[ -z  $dirname  ]] && echo "Project name required as an argument." && return

# get flags
verbose='false'
aflag='false'
bflag='false'
files='false'
while getopts 'abf:v' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    a) aflag='true' ;;
    b) bflag='true' ;;
    f) files="${OPTARG}" ;;
    v) verbose='true' ;;
    *) error "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
  esac
done

echo "$files"

echo "$HOME/Desktop/$dirname"

exit
```

The terminal shows:

```
Jills-MBP:~ jillr$ bash test.sh blah -f file
false
/Users/jillr/Desktop/blah
```

**Unless** I switch the order of the arguments, as in:

```
bash file.sh -f optional_arg expected_arg
```

Which the terminal outputs:

```
Jills-MBP:~ jillr$ bash test.sh -f file blah
file
/Users/jillr/Desktop/-f
```

So naturally, -f is processed as `$1`, which isn't what I want. I need to grab the expected_arg

**Constraints needed:**

- I need to allow for a varying number of flags (from none at all to several). Therefore, the position of expected_arg will vary
- expected_arg is a must
- I would rather avoid having to use another flag in order to parse expected_arg (as in, I want to avoid doing something like `$ bash test.sh -f file -d blah`)

**How can I satisfy those constraints?**

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind. I found this post: [Using getopts to parse options after a non-option argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140840/using-getopts-to-parse-options-after-a-non-option-argument?rq=1)

which basically says I can solve my issue simply by placing `shift` after dirname=$1

Which will allows for entering the arguments as

```
$ bash file.sh expected_arg -f optional_arg
```

Comment: +1, yep `shift` is what you need here....but it's generally better not to assume a fixed position for an argument, especially if you might have more than one non-option argument.  in other words, it's better to process the options first, then you know that whatever is remaining are non-options.   One of the reasons for using `getopts` (or `getopt`) is that you don't have to know the order of args, or even the number of args.

Comment: @cas feel free to post an implementation ;) :D

Comment: the implementation is your code above except you don't have `dirname=$1` or the test for `-z $dirname` **before** the getopts, you have them after the getopts processing, when all that's left is non-option args.   and you double-quote both `$dirname` and `$1` too, because that's what you should do when referencing a variable (or positional parameter), especially when they come from unknown/uncontrolled sources like command-line arguments.